# Replace text inside each line in Notepad++

Tags: html, regex, replace, notepad++, notepad

I have this:

```
...something...data-src="TEXT"...something...src="images/BBP/BBP0001/01SMALL.jpg"...something...

...something...data-src="TEXT"...something...src="images/BBP/BBP0001/02SMALL.jpg"...something...

...something...data-src="TEXT"...something...src="images/BBP/BBP0001/03SMALL.jpg"...something...
.
.
.
...something...data-src="TEXT"...something...src="images/BBP/BBP0001/48SMALL.jpg"...something...
```

I want this:

```
...something...data-src="images/BBP/BBP0001/01SMALL.jpg"...something...src="images/BBP/BBP0001/01SMALL.jpg"...something...

...something...data-src="images/BBP/BBP0001/02SMALL.jpg"...something...src="images/BBP/BBP0001/02SMALL.jpg"...something...

...something...data-src="images/BBP/BBP0001/03SMALL.jpg"...something...src="images/BBP/BBP0001/03SMALL.jpg"...something...
.
.
.
...something...data-src="images/BBP/BBP0001/48SMALL.jpg"...something...src="images/BBP/BBP0001/48SMALL.jpg"...something...
```

More precisely, I need to replace the "TEXT" value of the `data-src` attribute with the value in the `src` attribute, for each line.

Comment: That's nice, good luck.

Comment: I try to use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661601/notepad-copy-characters-on-every-line-and-add-to-the-end-of-every-line), but I can't make it work in reverse mode

Comment: You should read up on [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/) Notepad++ tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find what `(.*?data-src=")TEXT(.*?src=")(.*?)(".*)`

Replace with `$1$3$2$3$4`